# SQL Server - Filter by Highest Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, max

I am building a report that joins a few tables together. Everything came together perfectly minus one aspect. I need the cost2 field to show only the highest cost. Basically, an item goes through several cost changes through production, with the final cost being the highest. I need to query just that final cost. I know its a simple solution, but I have struggled more than I should on it.

Here's a simplified example of my query:
The MAX function does not work as I intended it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.item_no,
                table2.quantity,
                table2.date,
                table3.cost1,
                MAX(table4.cost2)
FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.item_no = table1.item_no
     INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.item_no = table1.item_no
     INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.item_no = table1.item_no
WHERE table3.cost1 <> 0
GROUP BY table1.item_no,
         table2.quantity,
         table2.date,
         table3.cost1
```

Comment: how would you identify the final cost?

Comment: Is that a typo on the last INNER JOIN a comma instead of a period? `table1,item_no` should be `table1.item_no`

Comment: Can you define "does not work as I intended it"??? If I were going to toss out some psuedocode for the definition of your query based on the vague description it would look exactly like what you posted. Help us understand the problem and we can help you find a solution. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @vkp it is the highest iteration of table4.cost4 for an item.

Comment: @xQbert edited thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.item_no,
       table2.quantity,
       table2.date,
       table3.cost1,
       table4.cost2
FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.item_no = table1.item_no
     INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.item_no = table1.item_no
     INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.item_no = table1,item_no
WHERE table3.cost1 <> 0
AND table4.cost4 = (SELECT MAX(a.cost4 ) 
                    FROM table4 a
                    WHERE
                        table4.item_no=a.item_no
                        GROUP BY a.item_no
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t1.item_no, t2.quantity, t2.date, t3.cost1, t4.cost2,
           row_number() over (partition by t1.item_no order by t4.cost2 desc) as seqnum
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
           table2 t2
           ON t2.item_no = t1.item_no INNER JOIN
           table3 t3
           ON t3.item_no = t1.item_no INNER JOIN 
           table4 t4
           ON t4.item_no = t1.item_no
      WHERE t3.cost1 <> 0
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Because you appear to want one row per item, the `partition by` only contains the item number.  You will get all the other columns for the highest cost row.